# highlighting element of a string which are inside an objects of string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to highlight a string which are stored inside the objects of string

**For example**

```
var obj = {
  0: "hello<asda223>world\n hhhhhh<sdasd2222>world\n",
  1: "something<asdalkdjl333>something\n"
}
```

now i want to highlight or make there color different which are inside <> these bracket can i do this in javascript ?

Comment: You can replace all instances of `<` with `<span class="highlight">` and all instances of `>` with `</span>`, and then insert the string as html into your document somewhere

Comment: Highlighting part of the string only makes sense if the string is visible to the user in an environment that supports text colors. Is that string going to be inserted into an HTML document? Please clarify.

Comment: yes i will print each string of a an object in a html page

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want highlight a text in a web page using javascript.
The idea is repleacing the searched text which is enclosed by  '' and the span should have a class with name "hightlight". This can be done in javascript or using jQuery in different ways.
Finally, you should define a class in your .css file.

```
CSS File:
 .hightlight { backgound-color: yellow; }


JAVASCRIPT:
var newText = "<span class='hightlight'>" + searchedtext + "</span>";
var searchedText= str.replace(searchedText, newText );
```

Comment: can you provide the code  as i just started programming i don't know how to do it .